# Turn home pc running windows into a server for a php MySQL website

Tags: php, mysql, windows, server, ftp

I have an old pc running on windows and what I would like to do is host a php MySQL website from that pc. I also want to be able to ftp into it with FileZilla from a separate pc... I'm looking for some free software or ideas on the best way to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally wamp is the way to go with windows to get apache/mysql/php going - http://www.wampserver.com/en/. if you are fairly capable and ambitious you could install a linux distro but that is a lot of extra overhead to learning php/mysql.

i'm not really familiar with windows ftp servers, but filezilla has a server as well that you could try: https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

Comment: Thanks after a little research I actually ran into wampserver it seems like it's the only one that's free and comes with Apache, php, MySQL basically everything I need.. Thanks for commenting